# Change Link Target property for Jump to URL action SSRS 2008 R2 (rc:LinkTarget)

Tags: javascript, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm using SSRS208R2 to create reports.
I display these reports using a ReportViewer control in my web application.

some of the fields in my table are  tags that user javascript:void window.open...
to opent a link in a new window.
I use Jump to URL action for my placeholders to achieve that.

**The Problem:**

1. My report is displayed in a separate domain.
2. ReportViewer Control renders the  tags with target='_top' property.
3. IE will not let any href='javascript:void alert....' action to run from a different domain Iframe if the target is _top.

---

**Questions**:

1. is there a way to define a different target for an anchor tag - i have search some places and found that the SSRS web application can use rc:LinkTarget=_Blank to chage all the targets but that dosent seem to work for me. are there any other possible solutions?
2. Can anyone suggest a different approach to open a link in a new window that will not hit a wall when the report is displayed from an Iframe on a different domain ?

Comment: Ad Q1: Can you tell us *why* using `rc:LinkTarget=_blank` doesn't work? It should, I think.

Comment: I'm using the Report viewer control in a custom page and not the built in viewer that comes with ssrs2008r2

Comment: That still doesn't explain *why* it doesn't work (I may be wrong, but I thought it should work). Have you tried debugging it yet? Where does it get stuck? In the JS? Doesn't it render correctly?

Comment: I tried the query string rc:LinkTarget at the built in reporting services web interface.. and that did not work for mi initially. the i realized that i changed the location of that parameter and it worked.. so i did some more digging and found that the report viewer control has the same property so i used it. anyway thanks for the help ..

Comment: Good to hear it's solved. Don't forget to answer your own question, so other visitors landing here via Google etc. can benefit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved!

I tried the query string "rc:LinkTarget" at the built in reporting services web interface.. 
and that did not work for me initially.

Then I tried to changed the location of that parameter and it worked.. I really don't think that that was it maybe there was a spelling error or something, anyway...

So I did some more digging and found that the report viewer control has the same property called LinkTarget I used it to define an empty string and everything works fine.

Cheers...

Comment: Mortalus is right! You should open the parent report, which contains the links, with rc:LinkTarget=_blank. This parameter add target=_blank to all links in the report, what cause all of them to be opened in a new tab/window.