# Is it possible to connect two SSRS reports which are in a different projects but in the same solution in TFS

Tags: reporting-services, tfs, reportserver, reportmanager

I am new at SSRS and
currently working on managing reports and dashboards in TFS and Report Manager with my team. So I have one whole project "Management".

It has reports relatively to Departments and Employees. It does not look good with hundreds of reports in one project. I am thinking to break down these reports into "Management_Department" and  "Management_Employees". Now the problem is Departments and Employees are connected with parameters.

My question is: is it possible to create these two separate projects but keep the flow(drill through) between Department and Employee reports, even if they are in to two different projects but the same solution.

I would appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Actually you can drill to any reports deployed on the same SSRS server. Try this:

1. go to Text Box Properties, go to Action, select "go to report" (just like how you normally config the link).
2. Then, don't select reports from the drop down list. Instead, manually type in the path of the report that you want to go to. For example, /FolderName/ReportName.

If you 're not sure the path of your sub-report, you can skip creating the link and deploy the 2 reports first. Then you go to the web page where you deployed it, "Edit in Report Builder". Do the step 1 above, then you click "Browse" to select from all the reports you've deployed onto the server. I found myself can only use the "Browse" in Report Builder, but not in Visual Studio. But you can still use this method in Visual Studio, only you can't test it until you've deployed. Hope that helps.

Comment: Than k you for all your responds. Greatly appreciate it

Comment: Just a FYI, if you use VS studio to dev your reports, it will **NOT**  work if you try to preview the report. you're gonna have to push it to a server to test it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, if you separate the reports into projects the **Go To Report** action will no longer work.

You could change these into **Go To URL** actions instead but then you'd need to map all the parameters and deal with the syntax issues.

I would see if there are enough non-linked reports to determine if it makes sense to break them out into separate projects.

[Passing parameter via url to sql server reporting service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078863/passing-parameter-via-url-to-sql-server-reporting-service)

[Change Link Target property for Jump to URL action SSRS 2008 R2 (rc:LinkTarget)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12248731/change-link-target-property-for-jump-to-url-action-ssrs-2008-r2-rclinktarget?rq=1)